# MongoDB, Express, NodeJS - connecting to database fails/ program loads infinitely

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/mean-stack-tutorial/) and when i try to run the following file with **node sbom-backend1.js** I do not get any output.

Is there something wrong with the code itself or is this an error due to my machine?

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"
const dbName = 'my-test'
const table = 'artifact'

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  db.collection(table).find().toArray((err, artifact) => {
        if (err) throw err
        artifact.forEach((value) => {
        console.log(value.scriptname)
    })
    client.close()
  })
})
```

I did the following:

- Checked if mongoDB is running and connected
- Checked for compatibility between mongod node js driver and my node version
- I created a new database test and tried with that one.
- I tried to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost
- Ran my code through chatGPT and more or less worked on all suggestions

I can also access the server via the mongo shell.

I am expecting to see my the entries I added to my-test in the console or that I see the error which should be thrown, however the system seems to be stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the DB name within the `url` string:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/my-test"
const table = 'artifact'

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
  if (err) throw err
  db.collection(table).find({}).toArray((err, artifact) => {
    if (err) throw err
    artifact.forEach((value) => {
      console.log(value.scriptname)
    })
    client.close()
  })
})
```

Comment: Ops, sorry these are not in the original code. Something went wrong copying the code to SO. I fixed the code in the question.

Comment: Try using `find({})`, also add another `if (err) throw err` above `const db = client.db(dbName);` to see if there is an error further up.

Comment: Stil nothing, however I should add the mongod logs show:

{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-16T00:04:21.831+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:60320","connectionId":4,"connectionCount":2}} ...

Which indicates that the connection is successful in itself, right?

Comment: It seem so - Try placing the db name within the actual URI string instead of using `.client()`, then drop the `db =` line, and replace `client` with `db`. Revised the answer again.